# Why can't I define my workbook as an object?

Tags: vba, excel

Why can't I define a workbook either of these ways?  (I have the range bit in there just for a quick test.)  How do I fix it?

This produces a `"Compile Error: Type Mismatch"`

```
Sub Setwbk()

    Dim wbk As Workbook

    Set wbk = "F:\Quarterly Reports\2012 Reports\New Reports\ _
           Master Benchmark Data Sheet.xlsx"

    Range("A2") = wbk.Name

End Sub
```

And this creates a `"Runtime Error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set"`

```
Sub Setwbk()

    Dim wbk As Workbook

    wbk = "F:\Quarterly Reports\2012 Reports\New Reports\ _
          Master Benchmark Data Sheet.xlsx"

    Range("A2") = wbk.Name

End Sub
```

What am I missing here?  I've been hammering away at VBA for a month, gotten pretty sophisticated, but this has me stumped.  I'm missing something elemental.
I just want to define a workbook so I don't have to type it all out!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's actually a sensible question.  Here's the answer from Excel 2010 help:

"The Workbook object is a member of the Workbooks collection. The Workbooks collection contains all the Workbook objects currently open in Microsoft Excel."

So, since that workbook isn't open - at least I assume it isn't - it can't be set as a workbook object.  If it was open you'd just set it like:

```
Set wbk = workbooks("Master Benchmark Data Sheet.xlsx")
```

Comment: and @Gaffi has the rest, and most germane part, of the answer.

Comment: I see.  I have to open it.  I left out the "workbooks" bit. I also need to "Set" it.  Why do I have to "set" it?  (I guess I should ask why do I also have to "set" a range?)  I am just trying to understand the language.  Is it because they are objects as opposed to properties of objects?  Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1408660 `Set` is how VBA assigns *object* variables. Since a `Range` and a `Workbook`/`Worksheet` are *objects*, you must use `Set` with these. In other words, your assumption is correct!

Comment: + 1 for explaining it so nicely :)

Answer (score 15):

You'll need to open the workbook to refer to it.

```
Sub Setwbk()

    Dim wbk As Workbook

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("F:\Quarterly Reports\2012 Reports\New Reports\ _
        Master Benchmark Data Sheet.xlsx")

End Sub
```

<sub>* Follow [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11054545/698590) if the workbook is already open. For the sake of making this answer as complete as possible, I'm including my comment on his answer:</sub>

> Why do I have to "set" it?

`Set` is how VBA assigns *object* variables. Since a `Range` and a `Workbook`/`Worksheet` are *objects*, you must use `Set` with these.

Comment: I posted another q to doug glancy above.  many thanks for your quick answer!